# After composer update Laravel project, getting VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough memory error

Tags: laravel, github, composer-php

I am working on a laravel project and after taking clone of files from Github.

When Running **Composer update** command bellow error is coming

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 868220928) (tried to allocate 58720256 bytes) in phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 90

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 868220928) (tried to allocate 58720256 bytes) in phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 90

Answer (score 1):

you should set your `memory_limit = -1` in your php config `php.ini`, but do not forget in production to let the default memory_limit and only do a `composer install --no-dev`.

This way, composer will do the install of your vendors based on `composer.lock` file.

You should also do the `composer install --no-dev` on your local machine to make sure that you have no developpement dependencies not compatible with the production environnement.